# Dropdown + Autofill

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a address list(name, street,city,telnumber)

On another sheet I have a form, where I can choose the name from an dropdown list. Now I want to get street,city, telnumber for this name. Is this possible with just excel formula? I know It would work with If but this get quite long when I have a lot of addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by data validation.

Copy your already existing range of values into the same sheet where your form is (you can go paste it somewhere hidden so it's not visible immediately (cell BB1 for instance).

Select the "data" from the menu bar,

When the ribbon drops, click on "data validation" in the "data tools" group

Chose "data validation" to open the data validation dialog box

On the settings tab, click the "Allow" drop down and select "list"

Click on the source field, and highlight your data range from your sheet.

Click OK.

[image: data validation example]

[image: drop-down image]